# What does "Hauptidealsatz" mean in "Krull's Hauptidealsatz"?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra, terminology

What does "Hauptidealsatz" mean in "Krull's Hauptidealsatz"? Thank you very much.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

[Google](https://translate.google.com.ar/?q=Hauptidealsatz&rlz=1C1ASUT_enAR516AR516&aq=f&um=1&ie=UTF-8&hl=es&sa=N&tab=wT#de/en/Hauptidealsatz) gives "Krull's **principal ideal theorem**".

More precisely, "Haupt-" is *principal*, "ideal" is, well, *ideal*, and "satz" is *theorem*. Compare to [Hilbert's Nullstellensatz](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hilbert%27s_Nullstellensatz).

Comment: (Nullstellensatz = zero-locus theorem. Null = zero, Stellen = sites or locations, Satz = theorem or statement)